# Use SharePoint lists as website CMS in C# using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, cms, access-token

I am currently building a website for a charity which MUST be bilingual English/Welsh. No online translator copes with welsh vey well, and I have access to Welsh speakers who are happy to provide translations, so I am intending to use SharePoint online lists as a CMS. I'm using VS2022 and C#.

I am failing at the first hurdle however, I have tried multiple methods of obtaining an access token and all fail.

I have registered an app in the SharePoint tenant.

The latest code I have tried is:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + GlobalVar.SPTenantID + "/oauth2/v2.0/token");
var request = new RestRequest("POST");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "fpc=AjMRWuGtzbFJgrxV0V1kMCkUHKO3AQAAAEqqRtgOAAAA");
request.AddParameter("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
request.AddParameter("client_id", GlobalVar.SPClientID);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", GlobalVar.SPSecret);
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
if (response.StatusCode == 0) GlobalVar.SPAccessToken = "Error"; else GlobalVar.SPAccessToken = response.Content;
```

This results in a status code of 0 and an error message of Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

I'm new to REST and OData so despite 55 years of programming I'm in need of help.

Comment: Look into how to request an oauth token with client credential flow. I think the content type is wrong. I think `grant_type=client_creentials` should be in the body and not in the parameters. I do not think the params for resource and cookie are necessary. I'm just going from memory here so you'll have to figure out the correct structure.